# MySQL query : search keyword like %

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was trying to query a database table by search keyword. My SQL is as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_name LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

where $keyword is from PHP form POST data. The $keyword is already processed by `real_escape_string` function. I notice that it the $keyword is **%**, all records are selected. How can I search for the `some_name` field with **%** in the content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the literal `%`, as explained in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_name LIKE '%\%%';
```

**EDIT:** Also note that you should escape the `_` character the same way, as that's symbol for a single-character wild card.

Comment: but why real_escape_string does not escape the % for me ?

Comment: Because real_escape_string has now way of knowing you're using the string in a LIKE statement.  It's only escaping for standard SQL safety.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape `%` with `\%` in keyword